# What is the best way to remove an object from a collection based upon what the user clicks in a Listview?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, collections

I'm using C# and I need to remove an object from my Listview when clicked. The Listview is filled by a collection and not just directly filled by the user, so I can't just use something like

```
foreach ( ListViewItem eachItem in listView1.SelectedItems)
{
    listView1.Items.Remove(eachItem);
}
```

because the object is still in the collection. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make pass the listView1.SelectedItems information into an object of the right type that I can pass, and I'm not even sure if that is the correct way to go about it. Thanks for any help you guys can give me.

Edit: It's a windows form

Comment: Is this WPF, or winforms? It greatly affects what the right answer is.

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case a backward standard loop could make your life easier

```
for(int x = listView1.SelectedItems.Count - 1; x>=0; x--)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = listView1.SelectedItems[x];
    if(YourConditionToDeleteTheItem() == true)
    {
        lvi.Remove(); 
    }
}
```